# apache spark load inner folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, hadoop

```
import findspark
findspark.init('C:\spark')
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

a = []
i=1880
while i<2018:
    a.append(str(i)+'/'+str(i)+'verr.csv')
    i = i+1

dataset1 = spark.read.format('csv').option('header','true').load('C://venq/uyh/'+ a)
```

i run code and i get the error;
  dataset1 = spark.read.format('csv').option('header','true').load('C://venq/uyh/'+ a)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

i have a "C:\venq\uyh\1880\1880\verr.csv" format a loop.
I have csv files in nested folders. I want to read them all with spark. however I get the following error. How can I solve this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

variable 'a' is a list of files.

`dataset1 = spark.read.format('csv').option('header','true').load('C://venq/uyh/'+ a)`

Here you are trying to concatenate a string 'C://venq/uyh/' with 'a' which is a list - which throws the error. Try

```
root = r"C://venq/uyh/"

while i<2018:
    a.append(root + str(i)+'/'+ str(i)+'verr.csv')
    i = i+1
```

and then use a directly

`dataset1 = spark.read.format('csv').option('header','true').load(a)`

Comment: please consider accepting the answer if it worked for you. thanks!